# How to stop java entity to get save while using prod database #java

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Using production database. Is there any way to stop save  anything from my code while doing debugging.
Is there any property file flag  by i able to use  only in reading mode

Comment: spring does not provide such flag, you have to implement by yourself

Answer (score 1):

Such a solution doesn't exist out of the box. You could try to use an other DB user which has no right to write when you debug your production code.

A custom solution (which need refactoring) would be to check the current environement of the application before performing write operations (e.g. with a pom parameter injected into your backend).

NB: it would be safer to have a second environement with a copy of the production DB to debug it safely